# Service Fabric call failed in Service Fabric Explorer

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When trying to expand the node view in Service Fabric Explorer, I get the Red box with Service Fabric call failed and the Fabric Exception is supplied address was invalid.  I have tried refreshing but get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your local cluster did not successfully install.

To check, try running the following from a new PowerShell Admin window:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster localhost:19000
```

If everything's good, you should see an output like this pretty quickly:

[image]

Otherwise, it will try to connect for a while and eventually return an error like this:

[image]

Try running the cluster setup script again and wait for it to successfully complete before going over to Service Fabric Explorer.